# How to send discord messages after waiting 1 second

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "!start") {
    var gov = setInterval(go, 1000);
    var onev = setInterval(one, 1000);
    var twov = setInterval(two, 1000);
    function two(msg) {
        msg.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/JZOCg5l.png ");
    }
    function one(msg) {
        msg.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/gTK3Vhn.png ");
    }
    function go(msg) {
        msg.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/3iVfYIR.png ");
    }
    function two(msg) { }
    function one(msg) { }
    function go(msg) { }
    msg.channel.sendFile("https://i.imgur.com/kOoyoZQ.png ").then(onev).then(twov).then(gov);
}
```

This is a very annoying task. I need to send these images about one second appart.
The current framework keeps giving me the following error:

```
C:\Users\maver\Documents\TestBot\testlev.js:197                                                                                  
msg.channel.sendFile("https://i.imgur.com/3iVfYIR.png ");                                                                
    ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined at Timeout.three [as _onTimeout] 
(C:\Users\maver\Documents\TestBot\testlev.js:197:17)                                
at ontimeout (timers.js:478:11)                                                                                      
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:302:5)                                                                                    
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:262:5)
```

I've tried this a multitude of different ways and am just about ready to throw in the towel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off. When you do `function two(msg){...` you are actually telling the function that you are going to pass it a new variable and that you want that variable called `msg`.  Because of that, `msg` (in the context of your function) is undefined.  You would have to pass in `msg` when you call the function from `setInterval()`.

There are 2 ways you can bind `msg` to your function.  The way that I personally like is this:

```
//...
var gov = setInterval(go.bind(null, msg), 1000);
var onev = setInterval(one.bind(null, msg), 1000);
var twov = setInterval(two.bind(null, msg), 1000);
//...
```

The `.bind()` function assigns the value of arguments. With the first argument of the function being called being the second argument of `bind()`.  The first argument of `bind()` is what should be used as the value of `this` inside the function.

The other way to do this is with an anonymous function

```
//...
var gov = setInterval(function(){go(msg)}, 1000);
var onev = setInterval(function(){one(msg)}, 1000);
var twov = setInterval(function(){two(msg)}, 1000);
//...
```

Also note, `setInterval()` repeats a function call ever period. You may be looking for `setTimeout()` which would only fire the functions once after a delay.

Comment: Thank you! The bot now sends the images as needed. Unfortunately, the images still right after eachother (except the first one) even with a 10000 ms delay. Any chance I can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

When you use setInterval, you should know it will call the function, but will not provide any parameters to it (or even `this`). One way to fix it would be by using bind:

```
setInterval(go.bind(null, msg), 1000)
```

This would work, because `bind()` will create a new function where the parameters are "magically set in advance".

Another option in this case would be to simply not re-declare `msg` in the three functions - in that case, javascript will try to find msg from the outer scope, where it exists:

```
function two() {
    msg.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/JZOCg5l.png ");
}
```

Third, you shouldn't be using setInterval, but setTimeout, which will only call the function once.

The fourth problem you have is with timing. First, all three setTimeout calls happen at the same time, so all three functions will be called in one second (after 1000 millis). An easy fix would be simply:

```
setTimeout(go, 1000);
setTimeout(one, 2000);
setTimeout(two, 3000);
```

However, that will completely ignore how long it takes to send each message (which may or may not be what you want). If you wanted to wait a second after the previous message is sent, then you'd have to do something like:

```
msg.channel.sendFile("https://i.imgur.com/kOoyoZQ.png ").then(function() {
    setTimeout(go, 1000);
});

function go() {
    msg.channel.send("https://i.imgur.com/3iVfYIR.png").then(function() {
        setTimeout(one, 1000);
    });
}

// etc
```

That would be very tedious, as all the functions will look very similar. So a better approach would be to create a list of messages, then have a single function to send all of them:

```
var msgs = [
    "https://i.imgur.com/kOoyoZQ.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/JZOCg5l.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/gTK3Vhn.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/3iVfYIR.png" 
];

function sendMsgs(msgs, delay) {
    if (msgs.length < 1) return; // we're done
    var remain = msgs.slice(1);
    var sendRemain = sendMsgs.bind(null, remain, delay);
    msg.channel.send(msgs[0]).then(function() {
        setTimeout(sendRemain, delay);
    });
}

sendMsgs(msgs, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executed immediately because you have to maintain the value anf promises you are using is not correctly used.
You can do it as follows :

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "!start") {
    var urls = ["https://i.imgur.com/kOoyoZQ.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/JZOCg5l.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/gTK3Vhn.png",
    "https://i.imgur.com/3iVfYIR.png" ];
    function gov(urls){
    for(let k=0; k<urls.length;k++){
           setTimeout(function() { msg.channel.send(k); },k*1000)
    }
    }
    gov(urls);
    }
```